# Login Failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' when connecting from a different SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have 3 servers:

**server1**: A server with Management Studio installed

**server2**: A database server with the database database2 running on the instance server2

**server3**: A database server with the database database3 running on the instance server3

I have created a linked server on server2, pointing to server3. When I execute an script using the linked server, it works.
When I login on server1 however, when I connect in Management Studio to server2 and try to execute the query using the linked server, I get the error:

> Login Failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Why doesn't this work, while it does work when I open Management Studio on server2?

Both server2 and server3 have the SQL Server service and the SQL Server Agent running under the same account, which is a domain account.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We just worked around the issue.

Comment: I can help you resolve this, if you're willing to edit your question with some additional details.   Most importantly, I need the output of the following command: *setspn -l <domain account running SQL service on Server1/Server2>*

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [Kerberos Double Hop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/) issue.

You can try by recreating the linked server by including the IP address. For example, In server2, linked server with `[ServerName], [PortNumber]` (Server2, 1433).

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting you have same service account configured on two different database servers (instances), I would suggest to have separate service account for each database server and setup proper SPN (command: SETSPN, ref https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241(v=ws.11).aspx)